# Get Position of floor in Kudan Android

Tags: java, c#, android, kudan

In unity, the code to get the floor's position is shown here. [image]

What's the equivalent form in android/java? I couldn't find anything similar in the documentation.

Comment: What documentation are you looking at?

Comment: Suggestion: Include C# tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Native SDK APIs work differently to the Unity plugin. On Android specifically, you'll want to look at the [ARGyroPlaceManager](https://wiki.kudan.eu/apidocs/AndroidDocs/dd/dd9/class_a_r_gyro_place_manager.html) class. As stated in the method description for getWorld:

```
The world is placed where the camera normal intersects the floor plane.
```

So the position of the "floor" is the position of the Gyro Place Manager's world node. By simply saying:

```
ARGyroPlaceManager gpm = ARGyroPlaceManager.getInstance();
ARVector3 vector = gpm.getWorld().getPosition();
```

You can get the 3D position of the Gyro Place Manager's world and by extension, the 3D position of the "floor", much like you would receive in the Unity plugin.